# Is it possible to install Craft on a cPanel temp user URL?

Tags: config, craft-features

When you create an account in cpanel you can use a URL to access it like http://ip/%7Eusername/, which is basically http://ip/~username/. Since the client is not ready to take down their old site and we are moving hosts, can Craft run on a URL with the ~username or %7E in the URL? They do not have a dedicated IP unfortunately. Thanks in advance.

I know the license will be needed, but can we change the URL to the real one when ready to go LIVE?

Comment: Assuming you have auth over the DNS,  why not just create an A record for dev.example.com pointing to new IP?

Comment: I do not have DNS access yet. They are working on that.

Comment: I keep a prototype domain just for this purpose.  There is no reason not to use dev.whatever.com when you control whatever.com

Comment: How do I update the license to the new URL when site is ready?

Comment: I have a few dedicated IPs I can also use on my server if needed. Just wondering how to update the license domain when ready to change

Comment: It will prompt you when you login to the new location for the first time.  dev. domains are not validated against the license anyway.

Comment: http://buildwithcraft.com/help/license-enforcement

Comment: Is using just an IP a valid DEV environment? I thought we needed to use .dev?

Comment: Our web service checks the following when determining if a domain is public. If any of these checks pass, we determine that the domain is not public:

Does it only consist of one segment (e.g. “localhost”)?Is it an IP address?Does it have a port, and is it something besides 80 or 443?Does it have a dev-sounding subdomain (e.g. ‘craftdemo’, ‘dev’, ‘local’, ‘loc’, ‘test’, ‘testing’, ‘sandbox’, ‘stage’, ‘staging’, ‘acc’ or ‘acceptance’)?Does it have a non-standard TLD?

Comment: So I have craft uploaded to a subdomain, but how can I get the system folder above webroot since there could be more than one DEV site? Since subdomains are setup like "/path/user/public/subdomain1" "/path/user/public/subdomain2", where and how do I setup the system folders??

Comment: Would I be better to just share the same system folder for all site and setup a config switch or something?

Comment: Or should I just leave the system folder in the sub domain folder to keep things simple for development?

Comment: I always set s custom path on sun domains for that reason.  Just add another level in the path when you add the sub, that way you can keep it above the HTML root. I use /subdomains/sitename/public_html/  then put Craft in the sitename directory.

Comment: Great idea Steve. Thx

Answer (score 2):

http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/multi-environment-configs

```
'example.com' => array(...
```

'should' work with an address like:

```
'123.45.67.89/%7eusername' => array(...
```

You might also try:

```
'123.45.67.89/~username' => array(...
```

Although using a proper domain name as in my comment above would be better.

Good luck. :)

Comment: Thx. I will try it. Was not sure if the ~ would cause any issues

Comment: I was just wondering if anyone tried it this way yet